# Expand stateProperties in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, prototype, expand, fabricjs

I would like to expand all classes of Fabric.js with few properties that should be serializable as well. I was doing it this way:

```
  var stateProps = fabric.Object.prototype.stateProperties;
  stateProps.splice(0,0,"name", "id", "creator", "dateTimeCreated");
  fabric.Object.prototype.stateProperties = stateProps;
```

It works for the object without the problem but "stateProperties" of all inherited classes are sometimes unfortunately "initialized" for the prototypes and my new properties are not mentioned.

Is there any way to call these lines before the prototypes of the inherited classes would be initialized?

Answer (score 1):

The reason inherited "classes" don't get new properties is because they're built during declaration (when Fabric is initialized). So at that point, they're using original value of `fabric.Object.prototype.stateProperties`.

If your goal is to include properties in serialization output, don't forget that you can always use toJSON/toObject with additional "propertiesToInclude" argument:

```
object.toJSON([ 'foo', 'bar' ]);
```

Comment: Ok, that can solve part of the problem. But how to work with stateful staff as for example: saveState  if I "expand" the base object with new properties. Wouldn't it be a problem? Are there any other problems I have to solve, if the properties are missing between stateProperties? I cannot use hasStateChange and use it for undo redo, am I right?